# Individual binding for unpacked array elements in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In synthesizable SystemC I can bind each element of vector of ports individually:

```
SC_MODULE(submodule)
{
    sc_vector<sc_in<int> >  SC_NAMED(in_vec, 3);  
};

SC_MODULE(top) {
    submodule               SC_NAMED(submod_inst);
    sc_signal<int>          SC_NAMED(a);
    sc_signal<int>          SC_NAMED(b);
    sc_signal<int>          SC_NAMED(c);

    SC_CTOR(top) {
        submod_inst.in_vec[0].bind(a);
        submod_inst.in_vec[1].bind(b);
        submod_inst.in_vec[2].bind(c);
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do the same in synthesizable SystemVerilog?

```
module submodule (
    input logic[31:0]   in_vec[3];
);

endmodule

module top ();

    logic [31:0] a;
    logic [31:0] b;
    logic [31:0] c;

    submodule submod_inst (
//        What should I put here?
//        .in_vec[0] (a),  /// ERROR!!
//        .in_vec[1] (b),
//        .in_vec[2] (c)
    );


endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.in_vec('{a, b, c})
```

Or you can create a array and assign individual value to it. Then bind the array signal to sub module.

Comment: .in_vec('{a, b, c}) works in VCS, but fails in Design Compiler: "The construct 'assignment pattern in port connection' is not supported."

Comment: Using one more array and assignments is a good idea. But it would not work for inout ports I guess.